# FFmpeg Laravel how can make ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy Two_BeSureToWearFlowersInYourHair.mp3 by Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

how can make ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy Two_BeSureToWearFlowersInYourHair.mp3
by Laravel FFmpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `exec` and `shell_exec` functions and backtick operator in php. There are also a couple of ffmpeg libraries for php including [PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) and [ffmpeg-php](https://github.com/char0n/ffmpeg-php)